# Displaying output in categories like Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know how you can display output from a function like get-childitem when it runs multiple times(array pipeline input)? I'll try to show it With an example.

```
PS C:\Users> ".\Graimer", ".\Public" | Get-ChildItem


    Directory: C:\Users\Graimer


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                            
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                            
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Contacts                                                        
d-r--        06.01.2013     01:23            Desktop                                                         
d-r--        02.01.2013     17:15            Documents                                                       
d-r--        05.01.2013     16:38            Downloads                                                       
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Favorites                                                       
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Links                                                           
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Music                                                           
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Pictures                                                        
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Saved Games                                                     
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Searches                                                        
d-r--        20.12.2012     15:59            Videos                                                          


    Directory: C:\Users\Public


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                            
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                            
d-r--        20.12.2012     13:57            Documents                                                       
d-r--        26.07.2012     10:13            Downloads                                                       
d-r--        26.07.2012     10:13            Music                                                           
d-r--        26.07.2012     10:13            Pictures                                                        
d-r--        26.07.2012     10:13            Videos
```

In my function, when I use array input and process { } Blocks, Write-output puts all the results in one table like it should. But how can I format it like this? Separate by Directory when displayed, while being stored as a standard object-array? Can't seem to find articles on it. It doesn't matter if it's only possible With compiled cmdlets, I'm just looking for some clues no matter what :)

EDIT: Added my code. Just creating psobjects and using Write-Object to display them.

```
Function Get-RecurseFileCount
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String[]]$Path = "."
    )
    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
        foreach ($rootpath in $Path)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Testing if path of rootdirectory exists"
            if(Test-Path $rootpath)
            {
                Write-Verbose "Getting all recursive subfolders"
                $folders = Get-ChildItem $rootpath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {$_.PSIsContainer}

                Write-Verbose "Starting to count files in rootfolder"
                $folder = Get-Item $rootpath
                $fcount = (Get-ChildItem $rootpath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Count
                New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $folder.Name; FolderPath = $folder.FullName; FileCount = $fcount} | Write-Output

                Write-Verbose "Starting to count files in subfolders"
                foreach($folder in $folders)
                {
                   $fname = $folder.Name
                   $fpath = $folder.FullName
                   $fcount = (Get-ChildItem $fpath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Count
                   New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FolderPath = $fpath; FileCount = $fcount} | Write-Output
                }
                Write-Verbose "Finished with filecount"
            }
        }
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

And `Format-Table -GroupBy ..` is not an answer. A solution would be to add a property called `root = $rootpath` and add a default view that Groups by the property `root` AND hiding it in the table so it's not displayed multiple times. The question is just.. how? :)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: add it now. Any function using Write-output will do since my code behaves as it should. It's Get-ChildItem that(DirectoryInfo / FileInfo Objects) that has that special something :)

Comment: I have narrowed it down to type / view defintions(don't know the difference) that are stored in ps1xml files. The FileInfo/DirectoryInfo types have a default view definition that Groups by(this is what I want) by directory but there has to be an easier way without creating a c# class, two xml files and manually updating the PS session With the New xml files. Anyone who can simplify how this  all Works? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the `GroupBy` information in your view in a `format.ps1xml` file and update the format data to get the desired behaviour. There is no getting out of writing the `ps1xml` and loading it in your session.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315396.aspx

Comment: But how can I make sure only my objects are using the view in my.format.ps1xml without using 'ft -view myview' ? The objects is pscustomobject and I got other functions returns other customobjects.

Comment: http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/powershell-custom-objects-with-format-files/ Injection is described here. Just what I wanted. And EZOut (http://ezout.start-automating.com/) is now a must-have module! :)